# Flash Side-scroller game objects shakes while hero is moving

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5, side-scroller, citrus-engine

I'm trying to create a `side-scroller` game using `Citrus Engine` in **Flash CS5**
Everything is done but just when the **Hero** is moving everything starts shaking!
Before I was making all objects as `Movie Clips` and i changed it to some images and its still the same...

Any idea what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because as your character moves across non-whole pixels (e.g. 10.5 pixels across), the other elements in the scene will round themselves to the nearest whole pixels. This means they 'dance' across a pixel as they are positioned by rounding down and rounding up.